# why does using jquery sortable prevent contentEditable attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jquery [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) is pretty cut and dried. However, when I try to make the content editable, it won't work. Disabling sortable shows me that my

```
$(function() {
    $( ".ce" ).attr("contentEditable",true);
  });
```

does in fact work. Why is this attribute being ignored, and how can I prevent this behavior?

http://jsbin.com/alExeVO/1/

Answer (score 2):

`.disableSelection();` is over riding the contenteditable.

Can use `handle` option of `sortable` so that you can edit within the element without initializing the dragstart unless cursor is over the descendants specified in `handle`

```
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable({handle: ".ui-icon"});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/alExeVO/7/edit)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You have to dismiss the `sorting` on that particular `span` element with class `.ce` by `cancel` option, in order to make it editable. Please read here for [further reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel).

```
$(function() {

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({cancel: '.ce'});
    $( ".ce" ).attr("contentEditable",true);

  });
```

### [Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/alExeVO/11)

Comment: $( "#sortable" ).sortable({cancel: '[contenteditable=true]'}); works too